# IIS express, access to large video

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I'm using IIS Express, which installed with VS17.

Currently i'm developing asp.net mvc application, which allows users to upload large videos (e.g. 1.5 hours and 4 GB). 
For develop i'm using git.

**Situation**: 
In last release my web app allows to play videos on iis (by direct link, e.g. localhost:PORT/Videos/FILENAME.mp4) - these vids are uploaded from users;

From last release i made some changes, which doesn't touch IIS configuration and video module.
But i've got error: Now when i'm tryin' to play video by direct link i'm getting nothing (default html player cant play video [[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDN7N.jpg))

And in dev console (chrome) message:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type video/mp4: "http://localhost:PORT/Videos/FILENAME.mp4"

Video file is OK (not corrupted).

Comment: Try setting the MaxRequestLength in the web config.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @KenTucker, i tried, but nothing changed :(

Comment: I've forgot to mention: on small video-files (tested on 30 min. & 600 MB) IIS works fine

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with IIS Express and VS 2017 on Chrome. Other browsers play the video fine. I tried to isolate the issue and created a single html page with just a video tag. Chrome will play the video if you open the HTML directly without using IIS Express.

After that I just moved the project from IIS Express to IIS and the problem was solved.

If you can, move it to IIS. The issue I believe is with IIS Express only.

Comment: hm, thx, i will try. but my problem is: only large videos are'nt playin' in iis, small videos (like i said) are fine in chrome.